# Rails fixtures for testing: selectively load individual records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

Do I have to put all fixture records for a model in the same file, named after the model? I would like to selectively load on some records depending on the test case, since the existing of the other data changes my app's behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have to place all the fixture records in the same file - fixtures are [placed before running tests](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html), and are designed to be in the database for every test run. If you want to add test-specific fixtures, you're better off using [factories](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/working-effectively-with-data-factories-using-factorygirl), which provide localized, context-specific ways of creating and mocking objects for your tests to use. You can choose to just have them instantiated, or saved to the database - providing you with flexibility.

The most popular factory for Rails is [factory girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) - you should give it a try!

Comment: Thanks. Yes I used factory girl before although it got quite unwieldy and slow. I'd like my tests to use historic data in yaml